# What the meaning of "0x48151642" in malloc_debug_leak.cpp

Tags: android, c++, malloc, glibc, bionic

Recently, I'm reading the libc-init code of android. When I read the code in `malloc_debug_leak.cpp`, line 70 and line 263, it said as follows.￼￼

```
#define GUARD               0x48151642 
static uint32_t MEMALIGN_GUARD      = 0xA1A41520;
```

I know the `GUARD` and `MEMALIGN_GUARD` meaning, but I really don't get the meaning of the value, for example `static uint32_t MEMALIGN_GUARD = 0x0001` is OK？or any other value. Does `0xA1A41520` have some useful info？

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lgzv.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMM5u.png

Answer (score 0):

> I really don't get the meaning of the value

It's a magic value, intended to catch common programming mistakes. See [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) for detailed explanation.

> Would `0x0001` be OK?

No. It lacks the "distinctive unique value that is unlikely to be mistaken for other meanings" property.

When you see value `0x1` in a certain location memory, such value could very likely be placed there by lots of different code sequences. On the other hand, when you see `0xA1A41520`, it is quite unlikely (though still possible) that that value was placed there by code other than the one that is using `MEMALIGN_GUARD`.